# Express callback not storing value in session

Tags: node.js, express

I created middleware to intercept all requests. If the user is logged in, I use that information to make a database call for a few other pieces of information I want to cache on the session so I can use it on the rest of my routes. The problem I have is that the value is not being set by the middleware below and I'm not sure why. I've debugged it and confirmed that a value is being returned in the database call.

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (true) {
        db.getvalue(req.user, function(error, response){
            if (!error) {
                req.session.myvalue = response.value;
            }
        });
    }

    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling next() before you set your session data, so that data aren't available in subsequent middlewares. `req.session.myvalue = response.value;` is runned in async manner and you should call next() from that point.

Comment: I moved next() the req.session.value and that cause the request to hang. Then I tried it with 2 next() statements; one in the first location and another where you suggested it. That also didn't work. The request didn't hang, but I checked my sessions table and the value wasn't set either.

Comment: I figured out how to force a save using req.sessions.save.